# Prints '+' to the screen 20 times using a loop and arithmetic operators

Tags: brainfuck

I have a simple Brainfuck program called "PuraPuraNanya", which prints the character `+` to the screen 20 times using a loop and arithmetic operators.

```
++++++++++[>+>+++>++++>+++++<<<<-]>++.
```

Here are explanations of what the program does:

- `++++++++++` initializes the value of the current memory cell to 10.
- `[` starts a loop.
- `>+` moves the value of the current memory cell to the next cell and increments it by 1.
- `>+++` moves the value of the current memory cell to the second next cell and increments it by 3.
- `>++++` moves the value of the current memory cell to the third next cell and increments it by 4.
- `>+++++` moves the value of the current memory cell to the fourth next cell and increments it by 5.
- `<<<<-` moves the cursor to the first memory cell and decrements its value by 1.
- `]` closes the loop.
- `>++` moves the cursor to the next memory cell and increments its value by 2.
- `.` prints the character `+` to the screen.

I expected the program to print the character `+` to the screen 20 times. However, when I ran the program, there were no errors and the compiler did not produce the expected output. Can anyone help me check and identify where the mistake is?

Test :

- https://ideone.com/phgfFM - No output
- https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-brainfuck-online/ -  Output : dot (`.`), one time
- https://copy.sh/brainfuck/ - No output

Comment: If your `.` is outside the loop, why would anything print more than once?

Comment: @CarlNorum Let's assume it will print once. How did that not happen?

Comment: Maybe the byte you printed was not a printable character.

Comment: Did you understand my answer, or what parts of it need more explaining? Is it clear why your program outputs a form feed (ASCII 12) and not 20 + signs (ASCII 43)? And that the interpreters you're using don't really support form feed? (Try the equivalent program ++++++++++++. and compare results.) If you somehow find a more reputable brainfuck programmer to answer this, they'll tell you the same thing.

Comment: @DanielCristofani sure. Your answer is correct. I just want to discuss Branfuck in more detail in this post :)

Comment: Okay. Would you like a program to solve your original task? Or do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. The memory starts as all 0s. Before you start the loop, memory is:

```
10 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The `>` commands don't move values as you said, they only move the pointer. Then you increment some cells. So after the first time through the loop, your memory will be:

```
9 1 3 4 5
```

with the pointer back at the (just decremented) `9`. After the second time through,

```
8 2 6 8 10
```

After the 10th iteration of the loop, memory is

```
0 10 30 40 50
```

and the loop terminates because you ended at a `0` (at the leftmost cell).

Then you move right one cell and increment twice. This makes a `12`:

```
0 12 30 40 50
```

Then you output a `12`.

Unfortunately, `12` is the ASCII code for "form feed", a control character and not a printable character. What that looks like will depend on your interpreter/compiler.

If you wanted to output a `+` you would want to output a `43` and not a `12`. And if you wanted to output it 20 times you would probably want to use a loop to do that; maybe you want one loop to help build a `20` and a `43`, and then another loop to output the `43` 20 times while decrementing the 20.

> Alternatively, you could just put `43` (`+`) commands and then `20` (`.`) commands, and no loops.)

Comment: `0x0C`(FF) is used in printed documents to signal the end of one page and the beginning of the next, right?

Comment: Originally, yes. Originally you would send ASCII directly to a printer. Now most of the control characters have fallen into disuse. I wouldn't in general trust things that handle text to interpret form feed as a page break now, some will, some won't.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent code in python which I think will be more self-explanatory than any written description, is -

```
i = 0
array = [0]*5
array[0] = 10
while array[0] != 0:
    i=i+1
    array[i] += 1
    i=i+1
    array[i] += 3
    i=i+1
    array[i] += 4
    i=i+1
    array[i] += 5
    i=i-4
    array[i] -= 1
i=i+1
array[i] += 2
# print(array[i]) -- prints 12 which is the ASCII for new page
print(chr(array[i]))
```

So if you dry run, you can observe that inside the loop, the memory cell will be updating as following -

```
[9] [1] [3] [4] [5]
[8] [2] [6] [8] [10] 
[7] [3] [9] [12] [15] 
[6] [4] [12] [16] [20] 
[5] [5] [15] [20] [25] 
[4] [6] [18] [24] [30] 
[3] [7] [21] [28] [35] 
[2] [8] [24] [32] [40] 
[1] [9] [27] [36] [45] 
[0] [10] [30] [40] [50]
```

After exiting from loop, increment the 2nd cell by 2

```
[0] [12] [30] [40] [50]
```

So now the cursor is in 2nd cell, therefore it is trying to print ASCII value of 12 i.e. new page. [See reference.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

To know more about this crazy esoteric programming language, [see this.](https://gist.github.com/roachhd/dce54bec8ba55fb17d3a)